# pandas group by multiple columns and remove rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is as follows:

```
imagename,locationName,brandname,x,y,w,h,xdiff,ydiff
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,SAMSUNG,0,490,177,82,0,0
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,SAMSUNG,1,491,182,78,1,1
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,DHFL,3,450,94,45,2,-41
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,DHFL,5,451,95,48,2,1
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,DUGOUT,VIVO,167,319,36,38,162,-132
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,DHFL,446,349,99,90,279,30
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,DHFL,455,342,84,93,9,-7
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,GOIBIBO,559,212,70,106,104,-130
```

Its a csv dump. From this I want to group by imagename and brandname.  Wherever the values in xdiff and ydiff is less than 10 then remove the second line.

For example, from the first two lines I want to delete the second line, similarly from lines 3 and 4 I want to delete line 4.

I could do this quickly in R using dplyr group by, lag and lead functions.  However, I am not sure how to combine different functions in python to achieve this. This is what I have tried so far:

```
df[df.groupby(['imagename','brandname']).xdiff.transform() <= 10]
```

Not sure what function should I call within transform and how to include `ydiff` too.

The expected output is as follows:

```
imagename,locationName,brandname,x,y,w,h,xdiff,ydiff
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,SAMSUNG,0,490,177,82,0,0
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,DHFL,3,450,94,45,2,-41
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,DUGOUT,VIVO,167,319,36,38,162,-132
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,DHFL,446,349,99,90,279,30
95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg,Shirt,GOIBIBO,559,212,70,106,104,-130
```

Comment: can you show the expected output for above dataframe

Comment: @NagaKiran added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take individual groupby frames and apply the conditions through `apply` function

```
#df.groupby(['imagename','brandname'],group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[range(0,len(x),2)] if x['xdiff'].lt(10).any() else x)
df.groupby(['imagename','brandname'],group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[range(0,len(x),2)] if (x['xdiff'].lt(10).any() and x['ydiff'].lt(10).any()) else x)
```

Out:

```
    imagename   locationName    brandname   x   y   w   h   xdiff   ydiff
2   95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg Shirt   DHFL    3   450 94  45  2   -41
5   95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg Shirt   DHFL    446 349 99  90  279 30
7   95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg Shirt   GOIBIBO 559 212 70  106 104 -130
0   95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg Shirt   SAMSUNG 0   490 177 82  0   0
4   95-20180407-215120-235505-00050.jpg DUGOUT  VIVO    167 319 36  38  162 -132
```

Comment: Thank you.  I want the ydiff also included in the code

Comment: incorporated the change @Apricot

Comment: glad to help : )@Apricot

Comment: I am trying on a larger dataset where I have 1000's of images...I am sorting them by imagename, brandname and x - the alignment of the data is exactly the same as I have given for one image - however none of the lines gets removed....any thoughts on why this could happen.

Comment: actually i could not get any insight from that, condition is fine ,x.iloc[range(0,len(x),2)]   in this condition we are actually reducing the data, please try of assigning one group data to x explicitly and check the shape and conditions outside of apply function by for reduced dataframe, mostly it will work.

Comment: sorry...it works correctly...i made some silly mistakes